# emacs function to add include

Tags: package-repositories

When I edit `C/C++` files time to time in the middle of buffer,
I decide to add `#include` at the begin of buffer.
Save position jump to begin of buffer, then insert suitable line, then
jump back is boring.

I wonder may be there is standard (emacs build-in/elpa/melpa) solution to deal with such problem?

I mean some elisp code to find `#include` directives at the begin of file and insert new one.

If there are no, may be there is such solution for other languages for `import` (Java, Python), `use` (Rust) and so on which I can modify for `C++`?

Comment: FWIW, you can use `C-r #include RET` to find an existing directive, do your thing there, then use `C-u C-SPC` to jump back to where you were. The magic works because `C-r` pushes the starting point to the mark ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure someone will point you to an existing function, but it's easy
easy enough to write your own:

```
(defun add-include (header)
  "Add an #include line for `header' near top of file, avoiding duplicates."
  (interactive "M#include: ")
  (let ((incl (format "#include <%s>" header)))
    (save-excursion
      (if (search-backward incl nil t)
          (message "You already %s." incl)
        (when (search-backward "#include" nil 'stop-at-top)
          (forward-line)
          (beginning-of-line))
        (insert incl)
        (newline)))))
```

It first checks to see if you already have that include and if so does nothing. If not, it then checks to see if you have any includes at all, and if so
put the new one on the line after the last one. Finally, if you have
no includes at all, it puts the new one at the top of the buffer.

I'm sure usage would find some rough corners you'd want to smooth out.
For example, I just noticed I hard-coded `<` and `>` for the include
line. You can modify this if you sometimes need quotes instead.

Comment: Thanks, if no packages exists I will use your code.